# Grafana: Add annotation on multiple panels at once

Tags: annotations, grafana, grafana-api

I would like to add an annotation on **all panels** (graphs) in the Grafana dashboard.
I could add annotations manually one-by-one on all panels -- but I hope there is a better way how to do it although I didn't find any information [in the official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/annotations/).

I suppose I can write a script using Grafana API to create annotation on all panels in dashboard; however this seems like a complicated workaround more than an actual solution.

Do you know how to easily add annotations on all graphs at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. add an annotation to a single graph manually, as documented in the grafana docs: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/annotations/#adding-annotations. Make sure to give the annotation a "Tag".[image]
2. Go to Dashboard Settings (gear icon at the top) > Annotations > New Query. Set the Data Source to: "-- Grafana --". Set Filter By to: "Tags". Enter the tag you used in step 1. Save your changes and you're done.

[image]

More details in the official grafana docs: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/annotations/#query-by-tag

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with the same, but found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416641/3803228

In short, you have to go to your dashboard settings, and in the "annotations" tab, create a new query... that one will automatically display the annotation in all the dashboard panels.

This is the part that worked to me from @aussiedan

> Once you have your deployments being added as annotations, you can
> display those on your dashboard by going to the annotations tab in the
> dashboard settings and adding a new annotation source: adding
> annotation source
>
> [image: configuration]
>
> Then the annotations will be shown on the panels in your dashboard:
> panel showing annotation
>
> [image: result]

Comment: This kinda works, but you still have to use Grafana API, and my use case is a little different: I need to add an annotation in history, when unusual peek in graph occurs. Then it's pretty handy to do that for all graphs. Nevertheless, thank you!